# Laravel query MySQL JSON column using equal operator

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm trying to query a MySQL database table which contains a JSON column.

In MySQL the following query runs

```
mysql> select members from `conversations` where `members` = CAST('[1,2,3]' AS JSON) limit 3;
```

And I'm able to see the result from mysql console.

```
+-----------+
| members   |
+-----------+
| [1, 2, 3] |
| [1, 2, 3] |
| [1, 2, 3] |
+-----------+
```

However, when I use a Laravel QueryBuilder to build this query. It throws grammar error.

The Laravel code (inside a controller):

```
$memberList = $request->input('members');
DB::table("conversations")->where('members', '=', DB::raw('CAST(\''.$memberList.'\'AS JSON'))->get();
```

The error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `conversations` where `members` = CAST('[1,2,3]'AS JSON)
```

Could you please help me know where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `DB::raw('CAST('.$memberList.' AS JSON')`

Comment: Have tried that， no luck..

Comment: Can you do this, dd($memberList) to check the value of $memberList

Comment: @geckob well, I think you can see from the error output. It is just[1,2,3]

Comment: @aldrin27 yes, I put in {'members':[1,2,3]}; in the get request.

Comment: So your data is JSON. Why not use `JSON_ARRAY('.$memberList.')`? or try to use this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: @jinxuanWu This may just be a typo in the question, but there is no space between your quoted array and the `AS` keyword: `'[1,2,3]'AS`.

Comment: I think you just need a space before `AS JSON`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you must convert `$memberlist` to string.

```
$memberList = $request->input('members');
$memberListString = '[' . implode(",", $memberlist) . ']';
```

Then you can use;

```
DB::table("conversations")
    ->whereRaw("members = CAST('".$memberListString."' AS JSON)")->get();
```

I'm sure it will work.